# How to compute the sum with Mobious function

Tags: number-theory, mobius-inversion, mobius-function

Suppose $d = p_1p_2 \dots p_k$.

How to compute $\sum\limits_{lm = d} g(l)\tau(m)\log{m}$, where $g(l) = \sum\limits_{d~|~l} \mu(d)\mu\left(\dfrac{l}{d}\right)$

Any ideas or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the functions that you use? For instance what is $\tau$? And what is $\left (\frac ld\right)$? My best guess would be that $\left (\frac ld \right )$ is the Jacobi symbol. However this would always be $0$ since $\gcd (l,d)\neq 1$ and I don't know how you would define $\mu(0)$.

Comment: $\mu$ is a Mobious function, and $\left(\dfrac{l}{d}\right)$ is an argument; $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is obtained from the [Dirichlet-convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) $\,\mu * \mu\,$ and since the Dirichlet generating function for $\mu$ is $\dfrac 1{\zeta(s)}$ we [deduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Dirichlet_series) that $g(n)$ is generated by $\dfrac 1{\zeta(s)^2}$ :
$$\tag{1}\frac 1{\zeta(s)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {g(n)}{n^s}$$

Now you want :
\begin{align}
\tag{2}S(d)&:=\sum\limits_{lm = d} g(l)\tau(m)\log{m}=(g * (\tau\,\log))(d)\\
\end{align}

The [generating function for $\tau$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Series_relations) (the number of divisors) is $\;\zeta(s)\,\zeta(s)$ and to get (for every term $n$) the product by the $\log(n)$ you only need to compute the derivative (since $\dfrac d{ds} n^{-s}=-\log(n)\,n^{-s}$) so that :
$$\tag{3} \frac d{ds}\zeta(s)^2=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\tau(n)\,\log(n)}{n^s}$$
One deduces that the generating function for $S$ will be given by the product of the generating function of $g$ and of $\tau\,\log$ that is :
$$-\frac 1{\zeta(s)^2}\frac d{ds}\zeta(s)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {S(n)}{n^s}$$

But the [von Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Von_Mangoldt_function&redirect=no#Dirichlet_series) is generated by :
$$-\frac {\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$$

so that the conclusion follows...